# agregar clase css a un componente en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

quisiera saber como agrego clase a un componente mi codigo es este

```
import React from "react"

export default prop => {
  console.log(prop.className)
  return (
    <div className="sm:w-full m-2 bg-white shadow p-4 h-full">
      {prop.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

este seria mi componente.
Pero ya en donde lo muestro, adentro de este componente le agrego unos div y quiero hagregarle unas clases pero no me funciona

```
import Cards from "../cards"

<Cards className="bg-green">
      <div className="lg:w-4/12 min-h-card ">
        <div className="flex items-center ">
          <h4>Número total de visitantes</h4>
          <div className="flex flex-grow items-center justify-end">
            <Cardbutton isActive={true}>Hoy</Cardbutton>
            <Cardbutton>Sem.</Cardbutton>
            <Cardbutton>Mes</Cardbutton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <h1 className="font-bold">1K Visitantes</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <h4>Visitas por género</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Cards>
```

al componente card le quiero agregar clases desde donde lo mando a llamar si alguien me pudiera explicar como seria de mucha ayuda, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo pude resolver, para agregarle clases en donde lo mando a llamar tenia que tenerlo asi:

```
import React from "react"

    export default ({
        className="",
        children
    }) => {

      return (
        <div className={`${className} sm:w-full m-2 bg-white shadow p-4 h-full`}>
          {children}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

y ya donde lo mando a llamar solo seria de agregarle el `className="`

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo como esto.

```
// Componente Cards
. . .
<div className={`sm:w-full m-2 bg-white shadow p-4 h-full ${cardStyle}`}>
  {prop.children}
</div>
```

```
import Cards from "../cards"

<Cards cardStyle="bg-green">
 <div className="lg:w-4/12 min-h-card ">
 . . .
 </div>
</Cards>
```

Para no caer en el error de confundir el prop customizado por uno nativo.